# Magento 2.1.0-rc2 - Admin > Products > Catalog Listing

Tags: magento2, products, grid-serlization, magento2.1.0

Magento 2.1.0-rc2 - *Admin > Products > Catalog Listing*

Its giving an below error. I have installed it with sample data.

> a:4:{i:0;s:207:"Warning:
>   Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists::getCountryTranslation():
>   Cannot load resource element 'AN' in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists.php
>   on line 206";i:1;s:8248:"#0
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists.php(206):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Magento\Framewo...',
>   'F:\xampp\htdocs...', 206, Array)

Any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 2):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1_RC1CE.html#upgrade-rc-samp

i follow this instruction and i have no error when i open the catalog.

please read the release notes when you upgrade M2.

Good Luck